# Exchange messages through Ethernet network

Tags: ethernet, omnet++, inet

I am new to OMNET++, I succeed to create a network using Ethernet (using INET) But now i want for example to create a scenario where I can send a message lets say a float value from one node (source) to another specific one (destination).
the purpose of my work is to send an image from a sensor to a specific host via Ethernet.

I saw in the tictoc tutorial how to send a message between two nodes but is it possible to do such thing with INET.

Any one have an idea bout how can i do it if its possible?

Comment: Which protocol do you intend to use: TCP or UDP?

Comment: I want to try both but I tend to UDP more in my project

Answer (score 1):

If you need the actual data to be sent i.e. it is relevant for your simulation that **what** is the actual image, then you should create a new application module. You can see plenty of various applications in the `src/inet/applications` folder. You will need to define the application level message format in an MSG file and send that packet to UDP or TCP layer. You can take a look at `VoipStreamSender` and `SimpleVoipSender` for inspiration. VopiStreamSender does exactly what you want. It's just doing it with audio data instead of an image.

If you don't care about the actual data, just the amount of data transmitted, then you can take a look at the various traffic sources in `applications/udpapp` like the `UdpVideoStreamServer`.